# Should you always model a character to be rigged even if it's static?

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, rigidbody

I'm creating a scene that will have two characters.  For the most part it will be completely static.  The only animated parts will be an arm and a small head tilt.  I've done animation before but not on characters.  Should I design the character in a T-pose or is it fine to model them in the position they will be in and just rig the arm?  Will modeling them in a T-pose make it easier to make clothes?  I'm an intermediate to advanced user but this is my first dive into modeling a character.  Thank you for any help.

Comment: it depends ;) if you have lots of time and wanna learn rigging or you wanna reuse it later and animate more - rig it fully! if you are sure you will never use it again and just for that one animation, why wasting time with a full rig?